# How are pointers realized in supercomputers with lots of ram?

Tags: c++, pointers

I just learned that pointers in c++ are just again integers. So my naive question is what happens if a 64bit integer is not large enough to address all possibly available RAM? Couldn't this be the case in really large supercomputers?

Comment: Nothing prevents pointer from being wider than 64 bit. An 64bit of address space is 16 exabytes.

Comment: The size of a pointer is implementation-specified. If you are targeting a system with an enormous amount of RAM, the compiler would reasonably be expected to pick a large size for pointers. That being said, a 64-bit pointer can point to up to 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 distinct addresses -- that's 16 *exabytes*.

Comment: "Supercomputers" are generally not one computer. They are a network of many computers each running their own system. What makes them different from just any other collection of computers is that supercomputers generally have customized and specially built interconnects that are much faster than normal ethernet. So a pointer can only refer to memory on the current system. It cannot point to memory on the other side of the supercomputer because it's a different system in a different address space.

Comment: Research the Intel segmented address architecture as an example.  There are many methods available.

Comment: BTW, an implementation or platform is allowed to have pointers and integers that are different sizes (bit capacities).  For example, a computer can have a 128 bits for pointers and 32-bits for integers.

Comment: @Mysticial: It's not exactly _that_ simple. Supercomputers often have exotic interconnects, e.g. InfiniBand Remote Direct Memoy Access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long time ago, 16-bits was not enough address space for all of memory or reworded, computers needed more memory.

One scheme that developed was to split memory into *pages*.  Another integer would be the page number.  So to access memory, you would need a vector: [page number, address].

Along came the hard drive, and memory was swapped out onto the hard drive.  This swapping evolved into *virtual memory*.  Thus an application's memory was limited by the capacity of the hard drive.

So, if a computer needs to access more memory than it's pointer can address, other schemes are available.

P.S., most applications are not memory hogs.  The memory is used to hold the executables.  Most operating systems already have technology to swap portions of executables when memory needs to be use by other applications.

Don't forget that ancient concept of using external devices for memory, such as tape drives and disks.

Answer (score 2):

> I just learned that pointers in c++ are just again integers.

You learned wrong.  Pointers and integers are distinct types. In fact they are distinct sets of types. There are a dozen or so distinct integer types, and arbitrarily many pointer types.

The C++ standard says very little about how pointers are represented. Each pointer type has a fixed size, and like any other object type a pointer's representation is made of bits, so there are at most 2<sup>N</sup> distinct values for an N-bit pointer. On many systems, pointer values can reasonably be viewed as integers, but that is not universal. On some (mostly historical) systems, a pointer value can be composed of two parts, a segment number and an offset, and I've worked on systems where the 3 low-order bits of some pointer types are stored at the top of the word. And there's no guarantee that all pointer types have the same size, though they commonly do.

Pointers and integers are similar in that they're made of bits -- but *all* types are made of bits.

A 64-bit pointer type can address 2<sup>64</sup> distinct memory addresses. On a byte-addressed system, that's 16 exabytes, which is far more than any current supercomputer can have.

If, at some point in the future, computers are built with addressable memory bigger than 2<sup>64</sup> bytes, they'll simply have to use larger pointers, perhaps 128 bits.